# Trouble Printing Larger Character Strings C++

Tags: c++, string, char, ostream

I've written a class that is meant to keep track of errors and print out error messages if necessary. Right now I'm running it against a tester to determine if it can properly detect errors and print messages, but I'm having trouble with printing a very long string of characters. The code works fine when printing a small string of characters such as "Short Message", but when tested against a large string such as
"Some error message that is really long long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
" long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long" 
it fails and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

**Header**

```
#ifndef SICT_ERRORMESSAGE_H__
#define SICT_ERRORMESSAGE_H__
#include <iostream>

namespace sict {
class ErrorMessage {
  char* message_;
public:
  ErrorMessage();
  ErrorMessage(const char* errorMessage);
  ErrorMessage& operator=(const ErrorMessage& em) = delete;
  ErrorMessage& operator=(const char* errorMessage);
  virtual ~ErrorMessage();
  void clear();
  bool isClear()const;
  void message(const char* value);
  const char* message() const;
  std::ostream& write(std::ostream& ostr)const;
};
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ErrorMessage& err);
}
#endif
```

**CPP**

```
#define CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "ErrorMessage.h"
namespace sict{

ErrorMessage::ErrorMessage() {
  message_ = nullptr;
}

ErrorMessage::ErrorMessage(const char* errorMessage) {
  message_ = nullptr;
  message(errorMessage);
}

ErrorMessage& ErrorMessage::operator=(const char* errorMessage) {
  clear();
  message();
  return *this;
}

ErrorMessage::~ErrorMessage() {
  delete [] message_;
}

void ErrorMessage::clear() {
  delete [] message_;
  message_ = nullptr;
}

 bool ErrorMessage::isClear() const {
  if(message_ == nullptr) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
void ErrorMessage::message(const char* value) {
  delete [] message_;
  message_ = new char[strlen(value) + 1];
  strcpy(message_, value);
  }

const char* ErrorMessage::message() const {
  return message_;
}

std::ostream& ErrorMessage::write(std::ostream& ostr)const {
if (!isClear()) {
  ostr << message_;
}
return ostr;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ErrorMessage& err) {
  return err.write(os);
}
}
```

**Main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ErrorMessage.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace sict;
int main() {
   ErrorMessage T("Testing Error Message");
   ErrorMessage e;
   cout << T << endl << e << endl << "isClear(): " << (e.isClear() ? "Passed!" : "failed!") << endl;
   cout << "===========|\r";
   for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
      if (i % 1000000 == 0) {
         cout << "*";
         cout.flush();
  }
      e = "Some error message that is really long long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
     " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long";
   }
   cout << '*' << endl;
   cout << e << endl << "isClear(): " << (e.isClear() ? "Failed!" : "Passed!") << endl;
   e.message("Short Message");
   cout << e << endl << e.message() << endl << "isClear(): " << (e.isClear() ? "Failed!" : "Passed!") << endl;
   e.clear();
   cout << e << endl << "isClear(): " << (e.isClear() ? "Passed!" : "Failed!") << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean that "it fails"?

Comment: I've added the main file for more clarification.

Comment: It still doesn't explain what you understand by failure.

Comment: What I mean by it fails is that the main file outputs "isClear(): Failed!" rather than "Passed!" when it tests the extremely long string and the string does not print at all. On the other hand, when dealing with the short message, the output is "isClear(): Passed!" and the string is output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in your assignment operator:

```
ErrorMessage& ErrorMessage::operator=(const char* errorMessage) {
  clear();
  message();    // <-- Here!
  return *this;
}
```

I think you meant to write `message(errorMessage)`, which sets the stored error message, rather than `message()`, which returns the stored error message.

Try changing that and see if that fixes things.